# php string manipulation received by url after installing facebook app

Tags: php, string

I get this string from URL after installing a facebook page app on several pages.

```
tabs_added[255408179646]=1&tabs_added[197573531148]=1&tabs_added[225556742602]=1&tabs_added[201931451540]=1&tabs_added[205657687417]=1
```

I am looking for a way to itterate and be able to loop and echo each numeric value within brackets `[]`.

Comment: Are you getting those values over `POST` or over `GET`?

Answer (score 1):

The values are stored in `$_GET['tabs_added']`, and you can access them like this:

```
$tabs_added = $_GET['tabs_added'];
foreach($tabs_added as $key => $value){
    echo $key;
}
```

You should probably check if the values are present with `if(isset($_GET['tabs_added']))` first.

Answer (score 0):

The array should be stored in `$_GET['tabs_added']`. So you can try something like this to loop through it;

```
foreach($_GET['tabs_added'] AS $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of tabs through either the `$_GET` or `$_POST` superglobal variable, depending on whether this is a GET or POST request.

```
$tabs = $_GET["tabs_added"]; // or $_POST['tabs_added'];

foreach($tabs as $k => $v) {
    echo $k; 
}
```

You can also check if the param is present first to avoid an Undefined Index Notice for `$_GET["tabs_added"];` and subsequent Invalid argument Warning passing NULL to the foreach loop.

```
isset($_GET['tabs_added']
```

Answer (score 0):

`parse_str` is made for parsing query strings.

```
parse_str('tabs_added[255408179646]=1&tabs_added[197573531148]=1', $parsed);
var_dump($parsed);
```